# cloning a div into an obj and manipulating it

Tags: jquery, html, clone

I have the following code. The objective is to unhide the divs containing the class hidden and sort it to the top of the list. However, I want to be able to clone the #master div into an object eg. var x = $('#master') and I want to be able to run several manipulations on that object that rather than the hardcoded code.

```
<style>
     .hidden { display: none; }
</style>

<div id="master">
<div class="item" id="z">
    <div>
        <span>z</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item" id="y">
    <div>
        <span>y</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="x" class="item hidden">
    <div>
        <span>x</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="w" class="item hidden">
    <div>
        <span>w</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
function asc_sort(a, b) {
     return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;
}
</script>
```

In basic code I'd want to do something like

```
// clone #master into #temp for manipulating
$('#master').clone().append($("#temp"));
// unhide all divs with class of hidden
$('#temp .hidden').css('display', 'block');
// sort items alphabetically
$('#temp .item').sort(asc_sort);
// replace contents of #master with newly sorted #temp
```

Instead I want to do something more like this

```
var cloneObj = $('#masterlist');
cloneObj.find('.hidden').removeClass('hidden').sort(asc_sort);
$('#master').empty().html(cloneObj);
```

I don't want to do something like this on the direct code

```
var x = `$('#masterlist .hidden').css('display', 'block').clone().sort(asc_sort); 
$('#master').empty().html(x);
```

I want to manipulate the obj directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sort all of the `div`s in master, based on their class:

```
var master = $('#master');
$('div', master).sort(function (a, b) {
    if ($(a).hasClass('hidden')) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 1;
}).appendTo(master).removeClass('hidden');
```

If you need to remove the hidden class, you can chain that after the `appendTo(master)`.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xS4G/1/)

Comment: let's say I didn't need to sort it. If I just wanted to find all divs with .hidden in the master variable, how would I do that?

Comment: @archytect `$('div.hidden', '#master')` would give you all `div`s with `class='hidden'` inside `div` with `id='master'`.

Comment: @archytect remove the space in `div .hidden`; should be `div.hidden`

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to "unhide the divs containing the class hidden and sort it to the top of the list" you can do:

```
$('.hidden').removeClass('hidden').prependTo('#master');
```

Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/gmd4M/1/

Also you cannot have two `class` attributes on an element. In your html:

```
<div class="item" id="w" class="hidden">
```

is incorrect.

Comment: sorry, should have been more clear. I've updated the original post